# I want to know that $r^k \le C(1+r)^k$ holds.

Tags: calculus, inequality

When doe the inequality $$r^k \le C(1+r)^k$$ hold for $r>0$? I want to know the possible value of the real number $k$ so that the inequality holds. Here $C$ is independent of $r$.

Comment: Is k an integer?

Comment: $k$ is assumed to be a real number

Comment: Since $r>0$, $1+r>0$; divide both sides by it and see that your question is the same as asking whether the function $f(r)=\left(\frac{r}{1+r}\right)^k$ has a global maximum at some $r>0$, which can be settled by calculus.

Comment: I can show that it is true if k is nonnegative, but it seems like you are looking for a more general statement.

Comment: Would taking a log on both sides help?

Answer (score 0):

Following Mose Wintner's comment.

$$f(r)=\left[\frac{r}{1+r}\right]^{k}\leq C$$

We find

$$\frac{df}{dr}=k\frac{r^{k-1}}{(1+r)^{k+1}}$$

If $k> 0$ then for $r>0$, $\frac{df}{dr}>0$ and $f(r)$ is $\textit{not}$ bounded above. That is there does not exist a constant $C$ such that your inequality holds for all $r>0$ and real valued $k$.

If $k<0$ then for $r>0$, $\frac{df}{dr}<0$ and $f(r)$ would have an upper bound $C$.

Comment: Functions with positive derivatives can be bounded, which is the case here. Functions with negative derivatives can be unbounded on $(0,\infty),$ which is also the case here.

Comment: I was going to ask you for an example but I think $-\frac{1}{x^2}$, fits what you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

If $k=0,$ we can take $C=1.$

$k > 0:$ Because $0<r/(r+1)<1, 0<[r/(r+1)]^k<1^k = 1.$ So here you can take $C=1$ as well.

$k< 0:$ This time $ [r/(r+1)]^k= [(r+1)/r]^{-k}\to \infty$ as $r\to 0^+.$ So here no $C$ works.